# Grails <g:select> woes

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using the [Spring Security Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core).  By default this plugin has created three classes in my project.

`org.me.example.UserRole.UserRole`
`org.me.example.UserRole.User`
`org.me.example.UserRole.Role`

The `User` and `Role` classes are unaware of each other, but the `UserRole` class has both a `User` and a `Role` object.  The `Role` object has only one attribute, a string called `authority`.

My objective is to obtain all `Users` with a certain `authority` in a `<g:select>` statement.

Here is one of my attempts:

```
<g:select name="loggedBy.id" from="${org.me.example.UserRole.UserRole.list(fetch:[(role.authority):"ROLE_ADMIN"])}" optionKey="id" value=""  />
```

I do realize that this would return a `UserRole` list and not a `User` list.  Is there anyway to "join" my classes so I can retrieve the data I want?  Looking for the cleanest solution.

**Update:**

I think there was some confusion about what my classes look like, so here are the stripped down versions.

---

```
class UserRole {

    User user
    Role role

    //more stuff

}
```

---

```
class Role {

    String authority

    //more stuff

}
```

---

```
class User {

    //lots of stuff, but nothing that links back to the Role class or the UserRole class

}
```

---

Crudof's answer worked for me after some alterations.  Crudof pointed out that the package name `UserRole` does not follow Java package naming conventions.  This is true, but if I remember right the Spring Security Core plugin automatically creates that package and the classes in it, so I didn't mess with the name... But it has been a while since I did that, so I could be mistaken about it automatically naming the package.

```
<g:set var="desiredRole" value='${org.me.example.UserRole.Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")}' />
<g:select name="loggedBy.id" from="${org.me.example.UserRole.UserRole.findAllByRole(desiredRole).user}" optionKey="id" value=""  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your package names are not conform to common java-standards: package names should/HAVE TO start with lower case character. Otherwise one is confused, that it might be a class (where `UserRole` is a nested class of `UserRole`).
2. Basically your code snippet is fine (concept-wise). Note, that you cannot use double-quotes in double-quotes attribute values! I think this has stopped your progress. You can try the following:

   ```
   <g:set var="desiredRole" 
       value='${org.me.example.UserRole.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")}' />

   <g:select name="userSelect" 
       from="${org.me.example.UserRole.findAllByRole(desiredRole).user}" />
   ```

   Note that accessing the user-instances from the UserRole-instances is a groovy-sugar. See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections for a few examples.

Comment: I do realize about the package naming conventions, but when I installed the Spring Security Core plugin it automatically created the package and the classes therein, so I didn't mess with the names.  I was having some trouble with your code at first, but some after some alterations I got it to work.  See my updated question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: One more question crudolf, how could I do this same thing, but with multiple roles.  For instance, retrieve all users who have a role of `ROLE_ADMIN` and / or `ROLE_DRIVER`?

Comment: there are multiple solutions.. however, I think now you should move your logic into the controller: `def desiredRole1 = UserRole.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"); def desiredRole2 = UserRole.findByAuthority("ROLE_DRIVER"); def listedUsers = UserRole.withCriteria { role { "in"("id", [desiredRole1.id, desiredRole2.id]) } }.list().user; [listedUsers: listedUsers]` Now you can use `listedUsers` in the from attribute of your select.

Comment: I must be missing something simple, because like I said in my comment to @Gregg, I am having trouble getting the information from the `UserRole` controller to the view.  I get no errors with the code either of you have provided, but the drop down box in my view is empty.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong with that, but I did get the desired result when I used `findAllByRoleInList([desiredRole1, desiredRole2])` in my view... But it would be nice to have it in the controller like you and Gregg have said.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to do this in a controller:

```
def usersWithAdminRole = UserRole.withCriteria {
  eq("role", Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN'))
}.collect {
  it.user
}

<g:select from="${usersWithAdminRole}" name="loggedBy.id" optionKey="id" />
```

Comment: thx, I'm new to Grails.  I had tried something similar to this, but getting it from the controller to the view was giving me problems.  Could you expand on this.  Say I didn't want to limit this closure to just `ROLE_ADMIN`, but instead wanted to make the closure `usersWithUserRole` then pass in an argument.  I know the closure accepts arguments with this symbol `->`, but how do I input that argument to the `<g:select>` tag?

Comment: To get it from the controller to the view is as simple as putting it in the request. [usersWithAdminRole:usersWithAdminRole].  As for making it work for any role, just create a new method that uses the criteria code I showed you and pass whatever role you want into that method to use.  so 'ROLE_ADMIN' just becomes someRoleVar.