# Moving Grails logic from view to controller

Tags: grails, groovy

This question is a continuation of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069323/grails-gselect-woes).

The code below is from one of my views and it works fine, but I am having difficulty moving this code to a controller.  If my packages and classes are not clear from the code below, look at the previous question to see how they are arranged.

```
<g:set var="roleAdmin" value='${org.me.example.userrole.Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")}' />
<g:set var="roleOfficeProfessional" value='${org.me.example.userrole.Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_OFFICE_PROFESSIONAL")}' />
<g:set var="roleDriver" value='${org.me.example.userrole.Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_DRIVER")}' />
<g:select name="loggedBy.id" from="${org.me.example.userrole.UserRole.findAllByRoleInList([roleAdmin, roleOfficeProfessional, roleDriver]).user}" optionKey="id" value="${loadInstance?.loggedBy?.id}"  />
```

It may be a basic misunderstanding on my part, but I cannot get ANY of the methods that I have made in my controllers to work in my views, only the methods that Grails has created (i.e. `list`, `create`, `delete`, `edit`, etc.) will work.  Any assistance / recommendations would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *from* and *value* attributes don't come from methods/actions in your controller.  They come from, generally, the request object.  I gave you the code in your other thread to do this correctly, but here it is again, slightly more detailed...

```
class SomeController {

   def show = {
     def loadInstance = whateverYouGetItFrom
     def users = UserRole.findAllByRoleInList([roleAdmin, roleOfficeProfessional, roleDriver]).user
     [loadInstance:loadInstance,users:users]
   }
}
```

And then you would have a show.gsp which contains

```
<g:select name="loggedBy.id" from="${users}" optionKey="id" value="${loadInstance?.loggedBy?.id}"  />
```

If I'm misunderstanding your question, please give us some more details.

Comment: Gregg's answer is spot on.  The only clarification I would add is to note that the [loadInstance:loadInstance,users:user] is the important part of passing data from the controller to the view.  The line of code represents the "return" or passing of the map to the view.  It makes the content of items in the map available to the ${} templating syntax in the gsp.  Sorry if this is repetitive or overly simplistic explanation, but it seemed like that was where the confusion was founded.

Comment: @Bill Pfeiffer No, the explanation is welcome. I am learning Grails/Groovy in spare time, took a 2 month break and forgot a lot. Gregg's answer made me facepalm. The `optionKey="id"` argument in my view creates an error, and I am still a bit unclear on what the `value` argument is actually doing... but I can read up on both of those. My only other problem is how do I get pass an argument FROM the view TO the controller?  I understand the `[key:value]` part of the controller, but how do I pass an argument to the controller when I use `from="${users}"`?

Comment: Why do you need to pass something from the view to the controller to populate a SELECT?

Comment: Lets say I moved this code to a service so I could re-use it in a different controller. Since I have 5 different role types that is 120 possible combinations of roles, each of which would require a closure of its own. If I can pass in a parameter or argument (or possibly 5 in this case) I would only need one closure. Am I missing something about how this is supposed to work?

Comment: I think your logic is just misplaced and the fact that we're missing a big piece of the puzzle because we don't know what you're really trying to achieve here.   We can only piece bits together as you reveal more information.  All I can say at this point is the logic to determine which users to pass to the view should happen in the controller, not the view.

Comment: Since I've technically answered your question, you might consider accepting it and starting a new question (or questions) and possibly provide more detail.  This conversation is beginning to go well beyond  what this site is intended to be used for and more questions are being asked in comments.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I don't know what other information to give. I tried to give the most important info. In my previous question I stated exactly what I wanted to do, and gave the structure of my package and the classes involved. So to be as clear as possible here is what I am trying to achieve. I want to write a method one time.  I want that method to exist in a controller or a service, which ever is most appropriate. I want to be able to pass multiple arguments / parameters from a view to the method so it can return a list of users based on whatever combination of `roles` I give it.

Comment: i think, you try to create a method in a controller, and you are trying to call it from your view. this is NOT possible. the view only has access to: 1. the params, the action itself has passed to the view 2. the services, the controller has defined. In your case, you need to always give the set of users to the view, by returning it from the action.  however another option would be, that you use a TAGLIB, so that you do something like: <typoking:userlist group="ROLE_ADMIN" /> or <typoking:userlist group="[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]"/>. I think you should go like this! You know how to do this?

Comment: note: the mentioned tags would then render the complete select-box. taglibs are easy to write, i hope you get it ;)

Comment: @crudolf I will definitely look into a `taglib` solution, sounds like it may be the way to go in the long run.